The headers that should say Figure and Page individually both say LIST OF FIGURES
My first page of my List of Figures looks correct. It has the single header with "List of Figures" and then the sub headers of "Figure" and "Page".
However, on the subsequent pages, the "Figure" and "Page" subheaders are gone, and instead above are dual headers of "List of Figures"


Without code we have no idea what you're doing.

This is the List of Figures (LOF) section of my .sty file:
% Get the title for the LOF normal sized, centered, and at the right height. % \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-64.0truept} \setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0truept} % \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES} \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize\rm} \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

The first page uses \addtocontents to add "Figure ;;; Page" at the beginning.  It isn't really a header since it goes inside the text area.

Provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. We do not know your setup or documentclass.
